# DirectionResult has null routes and waypoints - Google Directions API

Tags: android, google-api, jackson, map-directions, google-http-client

My goal for this program was to poll the Google Directions API and plot the course by Polyline on a MapView in an Android app.

However, when I get the `DirectionsResult` back from the API call, trying to access `directionsResult.routes[0]` or `directionsResult.geocodedWaypoints[0]` results in a **NullPointerException**.

I am currently importing the following libraries using maven repositories (excerpt from my build.gradle):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.21.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.21.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.21.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.21.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:1.21.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.21.0'
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.10'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

My current code inside an AsyncTask implementation with debugging calls commented out:

```
@Override
protected synchronized String doInBackground(URL... params)
{
    try {
        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                request.setParser(new JsonObjectParser(JSON_FACTORY));
            }
        });

        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        // to and from are both LatLng's
        url.put("origin", from.toUrlValue());
        url.put("destination", to.toUrlValue());
        url.put("sensor", true);
        HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
        //wait(1000);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
        //Log.i(TAG, httpResponse.parseAsString());
        //wait(1000);
        DirectionsResult directionsResult = httpResponse.parseAs(DirectionsResult.class);
        //wait(1000);
        //Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(httpResponse.getStatusCode()));
        //Log.i(TAG, httpResponse.getStatusMessage());
        latlngs = directionsResult.routes[0].overviewPolyline.decodePath();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

### My Debugging Process:

1. This is my printed request url:

   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.426870,-86.925083&destination=40.430092,-86.921679&sensor=true

Obviously it is a short but complete call. With elements of legs containing polyline points (which is what I assume I'm after). This JSON is the same as the response I got from reading `httpResponse.parseAsString()`.

2. Looking at some StackExchange questions, I saw some people suggested waiting for data to be received. I put 1 second delays between all integral parts of request cycle with no results.
3. None of the other parts of the call were null.
4. `httpResponse.getStatusCode()` returned 200.
5. `httpResponse.getStatusMessage()` returned OK.

Everything appears normal until I attempt to use `DirectionsResult` to parse the JSON `HttpResponse` with:

```
DirectionsResult directionsResult = HttpResponse.parseAs(DirectionsResult.class);
```

After which I get a NullPointerException when accessing the two fields of `DirectionsResult`: `routes` and `geocodedWaypoints`.

Has anyone had similar issues with this class? I've been thinking I might submit an issue on the proper google-http-client library GitHub page if this isn't resolved here.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that there were two things I was not doing right.

First, **I included no API key in the URL**, which doesn't explain why I was able to print a correctly formatted JSON response with `httpRequest.parseAsString()`, but regardless obviously an API key would need to be included for proper billing of my Google Developer account. Another change that needed to be made as a result of this, is changing the URL from 'http' to 'https'.

Second, there seems to be an issue with **requesting an Android API key rather than a Server API key**. I received this response when using the Android API key:

```
 {
    "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 128.210.106.49, with empty referer",
    "routes" : [],
    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

As a solution, when creating an API key, choose the Server option instead of Android.

Comment: Hi, I am getting error as java.lang.NullPointerException when I am getting routes from source to destination for Directions API in Android.Can you help me please ?Thanks in Advance.